# How do I replace space characters in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am trying to replace spaces with dashes (`-`). When I am going through my characters and every time I find a space between them I want to replace them with a `-`. For instance if I have a string: `A B`, it should be converted into `A-B`. Here is my code:

```
Sub prac()
      Dim x As String, a As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long
      Dim xcell As String
      x = "-"
      a = 1
      lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
         For i = a To lastrow
           xcell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
              If InStr(1, xcell, "") > 0 Then
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = strReplace("xcell", "", x)
             End If
         Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If there are multiple spaces, do you want a dash for each space or a single dash?

Comment: @dan08 ya anything between characters so A    B so if i have multiple space need to replace with - or i might have single space like A B and replace with one -

Answer (score 4):

For replace a substring with another substring you should use the function *Replace*

```
MsgBox Replace("the string you want to manipulate", " ", "-")
```

the " " stands for the space, and "-" is you char to be substitute.

So your last line of code should be (if I understood correctly your code):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = strReplace(xcell, " ", x)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

I see three and a half errors in your code:

1. Your `Instr(1, xcell, "")` is searching for an empty String. Try `Instr(xcell, " ")` to detect spaces (and then only the first of possibly many spaces).
2. `strReplace("xcell", "", x)`: The method you're looking for is replace(), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.
3. If you were to write `replace("xcell", " ", x)` (note the already corrected error #1), you wouldn't look inside the variable `xcell`, but inside the String `"xcell"`. Leave away the quotation marks to address the variable.
4. The half error is, that you don't have to search for occurrences of `" "`. The command `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = replace(xcell, " ", x)` will replace all spaces with dashes. If there are no spaces, nothing will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the "Replace" Function

```
Sub prac()
      Dim x As String, a As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long
      Dim xcell As String
      x = "-"
      a = 1
      lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
         For i = a To lastrow
           xcell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
              If InStr(1, xcell, "") > 0 Then
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) = Replace(xcell, " ", x)
             End If
         Next i
End Sub
```

The function name was wrong. Also you used the string "xcell" instead of the variable xcell and the second parameter must be a blank space.